# Prove that the sequence $(p^n)^{∞}_{n=1}$ for p a prime is a null sequence with respect to $| · |_p$.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Prove that the sequence $(p^n)^{∞}_{n=1}$ for p a prime is a null sequence with respect to $| · |_p$.

Here is what I have:

1. a null sequence is a sequence that maps to zero.
2. $| · |_p=p^{-vp(\cdot)}$

So, using (1) and (2) it seems obvious that for $|p^{n}|_p=p^{-vp(p^{n})}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty,p^{-vp(p^{n})}\rightarrow 0 $, which is a null sequence. However, I am having trouble putting this into a coherent proof.

Please help me with suggestion on how to get this started. Thank you.

Comment: I would accept this as an answer, but with the remark that what your proof seems to be missing is the observation that $z_n\to0\in\Bbb Q_p$ and $|z_n|\to0\in\Bbb R$ are equivalent conditions.